# How to get the next ID of autogenerated column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an autogenerated column `ID` in my table `class`. While inserting i want to fetch the value of auto ID which is suppose to be generated for that column while inserting and concat to a value to be put in `REF` column which is a 6 digit unique key.

How can i find the `ID` of next column to be generated, it is easy to add a `1` to the previous `ID` but what if the previous id is deleted? please help me to understand how to go about this issue.

I dont want the `ID` of deleted item to be given to a fresh item.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to fetch the next ID, because what happens if you fetch that ID and another process gets it at the same time. Should the DB return both of you the same ID? 

What you can do is fetch the ID of the just inserted row, and based on that UPDATE the reference column in another query!

Comment: You **cannot** - period. The value of an `IDENTITY` column is **NOT** determined until you actually insert the row into the table. You cannot determine that value ahead of time, before the row is actually inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last created identity value in your current scope. The next value will be incremented from that, but you can't be sure that it will be in your scope, another scope or what. Deletions do not affect what the next value will be.

Why would you need the "next value"?